# Trouble with loops inside list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I has to use a construct like

```
string json = await SendGraphGetRequest("/users", null);
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var values = (JArray)jsonObj["value"];

foreach (var value in values)

List<Users> Users = new List<Models.Users>()
            {
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                };
            };
```

How i have to correct the syntax?

I want to bring values from the json Obj in to the list.

Comment: you're using a collection initializer.  You can't put a loop inside that.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have add some code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to break down what you're trying to do into 3 simple steps. First you need to create a List data structure to store your users. Then you'll need to add some users to your empty list. Then finally you can enumerate your list with a for-each loop:

```
// First create a list of your users.
List<Model.Users> users = new List<Models.Users>();

// Add some users to the list.
users.Add(new Model.Users())
...
...
...


// Now you can loop through the list
foreach (var user in users)
{
   // do something with the current user
   user.DoSomething();
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to bring properties from value in the user list

Comment: Do you want to create a new user for each value in the values collection? For example, if there are 10 values, then you want 10 users?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrites it with Linq

```
List<Users> Users = values.Select(value => new Models.Users( ... )).ToList();
```

Instead `...` or `new Models.Users( ... )` you can use your logic

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more information? Thanks

Comment: It depends what do you want to do. I pretended that you want to create `Models.Users` objects based on data from `value`. Some examples are on https://blog.udemy.com/linq-select/

Answer (score 0):

Is each `value` in `values` a `Users` object?

If so,

```
List<Users> Users = new List<Models.Users>(values);
```

The `List<Users>` is initialized with the items in the `values` collection.

Or, perhaps each `value` contains some properties that you would use to construct your object:

```
var Users = new List<Models.Users>();
foreach (var value in values)
{
    var newUser = new Users();
    //Just making these up.
    newUser.Name = value.Name;
    newUser.Id = value.UserId;
    Users.Add(newUser);
}

var Users = new List<Models.Users>();
foreach (var value in values)
{
    var newUser = new Users();
    //Just making these up.
    newUser.Name = value.Name;
    newUser.Id = value.UserId;
    Users.Add(newUser);
}
```

The rest of these examples do the exact same thing - they're just shorthand.

```
var Users = new List<Models.Users>();
foreach (var value in values)
{
    Users.Add(new Users{Name=value.Name, Id=value.UserId});
}
```

This is using Linq. It does the exact same thing as above. We use it primarily because it looks cool, but the syntax is different until you get used to it.

```
var Users = new List<Models.Users>(values.Select(
    value=>new Users{Name=value.Name, Id=value.UserId}));
```

It's doing this:

```
var Users = new List<Models.Users>([some set of Users to initialize the collection]);
```

and this is the set of users being used to to initialize the collection:

```
values.Select(value=>new Users{Name=value.Name, Id=value.UserId})
```

In other words, for each item in `values` select (create) a new `Users` object.